# Is there a way to interpolate a mixin in Pug?

Tags: pug

Is it possible to use mixins inside a large block of text, maybe by interpolation? 
I tried the following syntax, but it didn't work:

```
p.
    The molecular #{+intext(1, "Cooper et al.")} structure of 
    AACs causes them to bind to chlorophyll and retain
```

Basically, I want to create links to references at the bottom of the page and back from citations to this text. So the mixin could be something like this:

```
mixin intext(num, text)
    span(id= 'intext' + num)
        | (
        a(href="#citation" + num)= text
        | )
```

Now I know I can work around this by using piped text:

```
p
    | The molecular 
    +intext(1, "Cooper et al.")
    | structure of AACs causes them to bind to chlorophyll and retain
```

But the webpage is going to have lots of text and lots of citations, and pipes will make it too complicated.

Is there any way that this can be achieved, using interpolation or a filter? Or something simpler?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it. This can be done using a JavaScript function itself.

```
var intext = function(num, text) {
    var link = "<a href=\"#citation" + num + "\">" + text + "</a>";
    var wrapper = "<span id=\"intext" + num + "\">(" + link + ")</span>"
    return wrapper;
}
```

And then to use it,

```
p.
    The molecular !{intext(1, "Cooper et al.")} structure of 
    AACs causes them to bind to chlorophyll and retain
```

works perfectly!

Comment: This solves your specific use-case but doesn't address the actual title problem (interpolating mixins)